# How to display referenced foreign key value/name instead of foreign key ID in Xamarin

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I am creating a ticketing app. On my Xamarin, I am calling a Rest API to display tickets. In my tickets class there are 2 foreign keys from different tables, which are `Department` and `Status`.

This is my API code:

```
public partial class Ticket
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Ticket()
    {
        this.Notes = new HashSet<Note>();
        this.TimeLogs = new HashSet<TimeLog>();
        this.Uploads = new HashSet<Upload>();
    }

    public int Ticket_Id { get; set; }
    public string Ticket_Title { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Ticket_DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Ticket_LoggedBy { get; set; }
    public string Ticket_Client { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Ticket_Status { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Ticket_Department { get; set; }
    public string Ticket_Description { get; set; }
    public string Ticket_Priority { get; set; }
    public string Ticket_AssignedTo { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<TimeLog> TimeLogs { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Upload> Uploads { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser2 { get; set; }
}

public IQueryable<Ticket> GetTickets()
{
    var tickets = db.Tickets
                    .Include(t => t.AspNetUser)
                    .Include(t => t.AspNetUser1)
                    .Include(t => t.Department)
                    .Include(t => t.Status)
                    .Include(t => t.AspNetUser2);
    return(tickets);
}
```

On my Xamarin I've created my Models/classes as follows:

```
public class TicketBindingModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Ticket_Id { get; set; }
    public string Ticket_Title { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Ticket_DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Ticket_LoggedBy { get; set; }
    public string Ticket_Client { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StatusBindingModel")]
    public Nullable<int> Ticket_Status { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Ticket_Department { get; set; }
    public string Ticket_Description { get; set; }
    public string Ticket_Priority { get; set; }
    public string Ticket_AssignedTo { get; set; }

    public StatusBindingModel StatusBindingModel { get; set; }
}

public class StatusBindingModel
{
    public StatusBindingModel()
    {
        this.Tickets = new HashSet<TicketBindingModel>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Status_Id { get; set; }
    public string Status_Title { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Ticket_Status")]
    public virtual ICollection<TicketBindingModel> Tickets { get; set; }
}
```

This is my view model code to call API:

```
public class TicketsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ApiServices _apiServices = new ApiServices();
    private List<TicketBindingModel> _tickets;
    
    public List<TicketBindingModel> Tickets 
    {
        get { return _tickets; }
        set { _tickets = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private List<StatusBindingModel> _status;

    public List<StatusBindingModel> Status
    {
        get { return _status; }
        set { _status = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public ICommand GetTicketsCommand
    {
        get 
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                var accesstoken = Settings.AccessToken;
                Status = await _apiServices.GetAllStatus(accesstoken);
                Tickets = await _apiServices.GetAllTickets(accesstoken);
            });
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

This is my `GetAllTickets` method which is called:

```
public async Task<List<TicketBindingModel>> GetAllTickets(string accessToken)
{
    var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
    httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };

    var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

    var json = await client.GetStringAsync("https://192.168.236.84:45455/api/Tickets1/");

    var tickets = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TicketBindingModel>>(json);

    var statusCheck = new ObservableCollection<TicketBindingModel>(tickets);

    return tickets;
}
```

And this is my Xaml markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:EasyJobsApp.ViewModel"
             x:Class="EasyJobsApp.Views.TicketsPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:TicketsViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>
        <Button Command="{Binding GetTicketsCommand}" Text="View Tickets"/>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Tickets}" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None" ItemTapped="TicketsListView_ItemTapped">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!--<ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Padding="20,10">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Category}"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>-->
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="10">
                            <Frame CornerRadius="20" HasShadow="True">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
                                        <Label VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="18"  Text="{Binding Ticket_Title}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <Label VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding Ticket_Priority}"/>
                                        <Label VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding Ticket_Status}"/>
                                        <Label VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding Tickets.StatusBindingModel.Status_Title}"/>
                                        <Label VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding Ticket_Description}"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

When I run my application, the department name and status name do not display instead their IDs are displayed as shown in this screenshot:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCMzz.png)

How can I display the name instead of the ID?

Comment: This is because you declared the `Ticket_Status` and `Ticket_Department` as int in the model class.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT should I change it to string? But if I change the data type to string, it will still display 1

Comment: The problem is that the  foreign key vlaue is id in your model. You may need to use a middle class to get the vaue of the name.